apache2 how to prevent automatic directory listing for all except specific ip address
I want clients to be denied automatic directory listings, other than those from specific ip addresses.
What should I put in my virtual host conf file?
I've tried
<Directory "/var/www/myvirtualhost/">
  Options +Indexes
  allow from 1.2.3.4
</Directory>

but it has the effect of allowing directory listings for everybody.

If I'm not mistaken, you need to specifically deny everyone. An example of how we set it up at my work would be:
<Directory /path/to/your/dir>  
  Options indexes   
  order deny,allow  
  deny from all
  allow from 1.2.3.4
</Directory>

So you would need to add the order line and the deny line

thanks Bethsabet but those settings deny all users access to all files, even those whose full url is known. Except clients coming from 1.2.3.4
